# UIBarButtonItem position inside UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 4 UIBarButtonItem (penButton, textButton, highlightButton & stampButton) inside 1 UIToolBar and I am trying to get each button line up vertically, right now they line up horizontally.

```
NSBundle *currentBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 200, 200)];
    [toolBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIButton *penTool = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    penTool.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [penTool setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen-but" inBundle:currentBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [penTool addTarget:self action:@selector(drawButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    penTool.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    penTool.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    penTool.tag = 1;
    UIBarButtonItem * penButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:penTool] autorelease];

    UIButton *textTool = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    textTool.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [textTool setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text-but" inBundle:currentBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [textTool addTarget:self action:@selector(drawButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    textTool.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    textTool.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    textTool.tag = 2;
    UIBarButtonItem * textButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textTool] autorelease];

    UIButton *highlightTool = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    highlightTool.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [highlightTool setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squarefill-but" inBundle:currentBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [highlightTool addTarget:self action:@selector(drawButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    highlightTool.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    highlightTool.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    highlightTool.tag = 3;
    UIBarButtonItem * highlightButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:highlightTool] autorelease];

    UIButton *stampTool = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    stampTool.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 30, 30);
    [stampTool setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"approved" inBundle:currentBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [stampTool addTarget:self action:@selector(drawButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    stampTool.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    stampTool.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    stampTool.tag = 4;
    UIBarButtonItem * stampButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:stampTool] autorelease];


    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: penButton, textButton, highlightButton, stampButton, nil];

    [toolBar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

How can I fix this so they line up vertically?

Comment: so you try to make a vertical toolbar ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can make a UIToolbar operate vertically. It is height restricted to 44/32 pixels. For your purposes the easiest way to go would be to create a custom UIView and possibly use Auto Layout to make it behave like a toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Just play around with interfacebuilder. I saw we can set Toolbar height by autolayout, but barButtonItem can't set auto layout.
Important thing: Bar button auto grown up to fix image size.
So prepare your images with need  size and set it to btn item.
[image]